# CertPath issue - HTTPS server does not show CA cert

Tags: java, ssl, https

The following code does what I think is expected of it - put a PrivateKey with the entire Certificate hierarchy into a KeyStore (which is then saved as a .jks file locally). I double checked it with KeyStore Explorer and it looks fine.

However, when I actually use the entry to create an instance of a HTTPS server, I can only see the signed cert, and therefore the connection is not trusted. The same thing does not happen when I use KSE to generate, create CSR and CA reply and import the signed cert.

What am I doing wrong? What must I do to make the Server to show the CA's Certificate so that the Browser will show "Trusted Connection"?

```
X509Certificate caCert = (new X509CertImpl(caKeyStore.getCertificate(rootDN).getEncoded()));

X509Certificate signed = CertificateMisc.bouncyCastle_Sign(csr,
        (PrivateKey) caKeyStore.getKey(rootDN, caKeyPairPassword),
        caCert.getSubjectDN().getName(),
        CA.algorithm, Misc.generateRandomBigInteger(), notBefore, notAfter,
        keyUsage, emailAddress);

KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
keyStore.load(null, null);

keyStore.setKeyEntry(dn, keyPair.getPrivate(), keyPairPassword,
        new X509Certificate[]{signed, caCert});
```

This is the KeyUsage of the CA and the cert that's signed.

```
KeyUsage.dataEncipherment | KeyUsage.keyEncipherment | KeyUsage.keyCertSign
| KeyUsage.digitalSignature | KeyUsage.keyAgreement | KeyUsage.keyCertSign
| KeyUsage.nonRepudiation | KeyUsage.cRLSign
```

Comment: What is the URL so we can check it?

Comment: The Key Usage and Extended Key Usage make no sense when presented like that. They need to be broken out by CA and Server. `nonRepudiation` means nothing and is not needed in any case. `keyCertSign` and `cRLSign` are for a CA and should not be present on a server cert. `keyAgreement` and `keyEncipherment` are for server certs and should not be present on a CA cert. What is the URL so we can see what's being served?

Answer (score 0):

> What must I do to make the Server to show the CA's Certificate so that the Browser will show "Trusted Connection"?

You don't do anything for the CA at the server. Its up to the client to trust the CA you are using. If the client does not trust the CA you are using, then there's nothing you can do about it (sans asking the user to trust the CA you are using).

It *is* your responsibility to send the server certificate, and any intermediate certificates required to build a path from the server certificate to the CA certificate. This avoids the "which directory" problem, and its a well known problem in PKI. Essentially, the "which directory" problem means the client does *not* know where to go to fetch a missing intermediate certificate. To avoid the problem, you send them during the handshake.

---

> What am I doing wrong?

Just guessing, but one of two things are happening (sans something obvious, like an expired certificate or incorrect key usage).

First, the client does not trust the CA the server is using. To fix it, ask the user to trust your CA; or use a different CA that the client software trusts.

Second, send the missing intermediate certificates required to build a path from the server's certificate to the CA certificate.

Comment: the idea is for the client to trust the CA, which will then trust whatever cert the CA signs. my question is about wat can be done to fix the CertPath problem that I have, and why the HTTPS server only sends the HTTPS server cert alone, and not together with the CA cert. it works properly when I generate the HTTPS cert, sign it with the CA cert using KSE. as I have said, I put the Signed Cert and CA Cert into the KeyStore's entry, however, only the signed cert is sent to the client during the HTTPS session. I'd like to fix this peculiar problem.

Comment: I have also updated the question with the KeyUsage properties that are in the certificate in question. Please take a look, thank you very much. The certificate is not expired.

Comment: "... server only sends the HTTPS server cert alone, and not together with the CA cert..." - the server is *not* supposed to send the CA certificate. Its only supposed to send the server certificate and the intermediate certificates required to build the chain.

Comment: "I have also updated the question ..." - what's the URL so we can check the server?